# What are the radical names?

Tags: radicals

I noticed the kangxi radicals all have two ways that people refer to them.
For example: `氵` is sometimes called `shuǐ`, sometimes called 三点水. `饣` is sometimes called `shí` or 食字旁.

What are the correct names for the radicals as radicals?

there's lots of these on [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Chinese_%28Mandarin%29/Radicals) and in the other way at [archchinese.com](http://www.archchinese.com/arch_chinese_radicals.html).

Comment: 三点水 or 水字旁 both indicates radical names. `三点` helps you visualize the radical. `字旁` means the radical's position is at the side. `字头` means it is at the top.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, 三点水 and shui3 are all correct names for 氵, so for 饣.

Actually, 氵is also 水, just in another face. 
You can know this by comparing Chinese Seal Character(小篆)
河:http://www.zdic.net/z/1c/zy/6CB3.htm
水:http://www.zdic.net/z/1c/zy/6C34.htm

三点水 is more formal, shui3 is most used in computer world.

Hope my explanation can help you understand this further.

Comment: 1. `水` isn't used only in the computer world. instead, it's rarely used. 2. `水`/`水部` is much more formal than `三点水`. look at 《说文解字》 河 从水可聲.

Answer (score 3):

They are called 部首. And, in antique dictionaries like 康熙字典, they are referred to as 部. It is very formal and scholarly to address the whole bunch of characters containing 氵 or 水(at the bottom) or other parts showing links to 水 as 水部. The logic here is ''the original character of the radical' + 部', following the rules of **classical** Chinese.

However, in everyday life, when we describe how to write an unfamiliar character or admiring calligraphy, we cannot address both 氵 and 水 as 水, because they are too vague for radicals in different positions. Popular names are called for, and here I enclose a list of popular name for radicals found on wikipedia.

[Popular Names for Radicals(Chinese)](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%83%A8%E9%A6%96#.E5.81.8F.E6.97.81.E7.9A.84.E4.BF.97.E7.A8.B1)

Answer (score 1):

As a native Chinese speaker, My teacher told me that `氵` called `三点水` and `饣` called `食字旁`.

Actually, we never call `氵` as `水`. It's a little strange. The [link wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Chinese_%28Mandarin%29/Radicals) you gave is exactly the right answer to your question.

Comment: `水` is never called in daily life. However, `水` is much more formal than `三点水`.

Comment: @MikeManilone when we call radicals we never call it 水.

Comment: I call it `水部` or `X字从水` :-)

Answer (score -1):

The wiki link is correct. 氵is 三点水 and 饣is 食字旁. I don't think [citation needed] 氵is a character with a real meaning. Didn't find it in the Kangxi Dictionary. I only use its pinyin "shui3" when I want to type it with a pinyin input method.

P.S. Almost all characters with the radical 氵is about water(河 river, 海 sea, 洋 ocean), and water(水) is pronounced shui3. And 饣-shi2-食 is about food/diet.